# How to refer to pipeline steps, to use feature_importance_ on a Pipeline?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pipeline, imblearn

I am using the make_pipeline function from imblearn, to make some data preparation and modelling. Now i want to use the feature_importance_ method on my model. But as my model is part of my pipeline i cant use this method. So I Want to refer to the model inside of my pipeline. Herefore I modified my pipeline code a bit, to give my pipeline steps specific names. But this doesn't work.

My Code:

```
my_pipeline = make_pipeline([( make_column_transformer(
        (make_pipeline(
            MinMaxScaler() 
        ), ['column_a','column_b']),
        remainder="passthrough")),       
        (PCA()),
                         (SMOTE()),
     ("classifier",RandomForestClassifier())])
```

Answer (score 0):

just have to remove the lableing and a few brackets, as make_pipeline do it by itself and then i can use the index 3

```
my_pipeline[3]
```